# Coupling application data to b2c user account

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Forgive my amateur question, however, I can't seem to find an answer on google/stackoverflow.

I created an app (Xamarin) and I want to store application data in a database, for example an Azure SQL database. I created and integrated a tenant in azure b2c for handling user accounts in the app.

I would like to somehow relate data in my "own" database to user accounts in b2c (is this strange?). All I can find is that you can create custom user attributes but this seems, in my opinion, pretty limited. So I need something unique from b2c that "cannot" change to relate to from my own database.

Seems to me like common use case, what is the preferred approach and is there some unique attribute that I can relate to? (object id maybe??)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Users in an Azure AD B2C tenant are identified by the **objectId** property of [the **user** object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#user-entity).

This **objectId** property is immutable.

It is common for tokens, which are issued by policies to applications, to contain the **sub** and/or **oid** claim/s, which are mapped from the **objectId** property.

This enables applications to cross-reference their "own" data for users.

Comment: Thanks, however, let me check if I understand correctly; I can put the objectid as a "foreign key" in my own database. Another option is to extend the user data in the AD B2C tenant with own "fields" (called claims?) in order to avoid a custom database altogether. Correct?